# get address corresponding to lattitude and longitude in google map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-api-2, reverse-geocoding

Hi in my application i am getting the lattitude and longitude of a location.I want to convert that points into address, when i try to do so iam getting error

> java.io.IOException: Service not Available at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private GoogleMap map;
//Location location;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
         LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        LocationListener mlocListener = new GpsMapLocationActivity();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);


        if (map == null) {
             map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                       .getMap();

          map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
        return true;
    }



        private class GpsMapLocationActivity implements LocationListener{

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (location != null) {
                      /*final GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                          (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                          (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));*/

                    /*   String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);address.toString();
                      Log.i("ADRESSS", ""+point);*/
                    double latitude=location.getLatitude();

                    double longitude=location.getLongitude();

                    LatLng loca=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

                     String address = ConvertPointToLocation(loca);
                     address.toString();

                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" +loca,
                                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                       Log.i("Adress",""+address);

                       CameraPosition  cmp= new CameraPosition.Builder().target(loca).zoom(14).bearing(90).tilt(30).build();
                       map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cmp));

                     MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(loca)
                    .title("MyMap")
                    .snippet("My Map View")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_gps));
                     map.addMarker(marker);

}
}
    private String ConvertPointToLocation(LatLng loca) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String address = "";
                  Geocoder geoCoder=new  Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                  try {
                      List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                        loca.latitude ,
                        loca.longitude, 1);

                      if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                        for (int index = 0; 
                    index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                          address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) +  " ";
                      }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {        
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }   

                    return address;
            }
@Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        }



}
```

I am tried some codes but the error is repeating
plz help me thanks in advance..

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119130/android-java-io-ioexception-service-not-available

Comment: May this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028830/get-current-location-address-for-android-app
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android